# Self Sizing Table View Cells isn't working

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I set the `estimatedRowHeight` to a constant and `rowHeight` to `UITableViewAutomaticDimension` but the table view cell is still not resizing to the detailTextLabel of my cell. Where am I going wrong?

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 130.0
    tableView.tableFooterView = UIView()
    tableView.separatorInset.left = 50
    tableView.registerClass(CommentCellView.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: cellid)
    tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension


}

override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) {
    tableView.reloadData()
}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(cellid, forIndexPath: indexPath) as! CommentCellView

    return cell
}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return 5

}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, estimatedHeightForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGFloat {
    return 60.0
}
```

The UITableViewCell class:

```
class CommentCellView: UITableViewCell {
    override init(style: UITableViewCellStyle, reuseIdentifier: String?) {
        super.init(style: .Subtitle, reuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)

        detailTextLabel?.numberOfLines = 0
        detailTextLabel?.text = "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum."

}
```

[image]

Comment: Do you have appropriate auto-layout constraints in your table view cell?

Comment: try to remove your `estimatedHeightForRowAtIndexPath` func

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set your label (called `yourText` in this example)

```
 var yourText : UILabel = {
    let label = UILabel()
    label.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    return label
}()
```

Set your cell constraints in this way and put the `setupComponents` method here:

```
 required init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)!
        setupComponents()
    }

    override init(style: UITableViewCellStyle, reuseIdentifier: String?) {
        super.init(style: .Subtitle, reuseIdentifier: "CellId")

        setupComponents()

    }

        func setupComponents(){



    self.addSubview(yourText)

    yourText.leftAnchor.constraintEqualToAnchor(self.leftAnchor, constant: 6).active = true
            yourText.centerYAnchor.constraintEqualToAnchor(self.centerYAnchor).active = true
            yourText.widthAnchor.constraintEqualToConstant(110).active = true

    yourText.numberOfLines = 0

    yourText.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakMode.ByWordWrapping
     self.bottomAnchor.constraintEqualToAnchor(yourText.bottomAnchor, constant: 5).active = true
    }
```